# Have to refresh in order to precheck checkbox, depending on mongoDb value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function which is called on page load which checks the checkbox if a value returned from mongoDB is true. The problem is that I need to re-refresh the page to show the checked checkbox, or it will not show the result.

```js
function populateMonitization(data) {
  if (data.monetization) {
    if (data.monetization.avod && data.monetization.avod.is_video_ads == true) {
      $('#avod_is_video_ads').prop('checked', true);
      $('#avod').prop('checked', true);
    }

    if (data.monetization.avod && data.monetization.avod.is_display_ads == true) {
      $('#avod_is_display_ads').prop('checked', true);
      $('#avod').prop('checked', true);
    }

    if (data.monetization.avod && data.monetization.avod.is_no_ads == true) {
      $('#avod_is_no_ads').prop('checked', true);
      $('#avod').prop('checked', true);
    }

    if (data.monetization.svod && data.monetization.svod.svod_is_video_ads == true) {
      $('#svod_is_limited_video_ads').prop('checked', true);
      $('#svod').prop('checked', true);
    }

    if (data.monetization.svod && data.monetization.svod.is_display_ads == true) {
      $('#svod_is_display_ads').prop('checked', true);
      $('#svod').prop('checked', true);
    }

    if (data.monetization.svod && data.monetization.svod.is_no_ads == true) {
      $('#svod_is_no_ads').prop('checked', true);
      $('#svod').prop('checked', true);
    }
  }

  if (data.monetization && data.monetization.tvod != null) {
    $('#tvod').prop('checked', true);
    $('#price_inr').val(data.monetization.tvod.price_inr);
    $('#price_usd').val(data.monetization.tvod.price_usd);
  }
}
```

Comment: The logic you've shown seems fine, although it could be made more DRY. How do you retrieve the value form mongo? Under what event are you running this code?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This function is get called on page load and i am getting correct data in response on ajax

Comment: It sounds like you need to run this logic in the callback of the AJAX request then.